# How to export to excel jquery grid data using jquery

Tags: jquery

Can any one help me out how to export the jquery grid data to excel?

I have inserted one button call export?

```
$("#Export").click(function(){
    I am little confuse what should I write?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it with pure jQuery or javascript (maybe there is some ugly IE/ActiveX solution, but i want to have nothing to do with it :P ). I think you need to use some server side scripting. Here is a solution with PHP: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/